# @RequestMapping Not working in Spring Version 1.5.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring boot project. While I choose release 1.5.2 the requestMapping urls are not working. its giving me 404 error always.

Can somebody please confirm me if any tags are missing or any setting change in version. or any other thins which i missed.

POM.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.prizy</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProductApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ProductApi</name>
    <description>Project for Product Managment</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Controller:

```
package com.prizy.controller;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.prizy.model.Product;
import com.prizy.service.ProductService;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productService.getAllProducts();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public String getString() {
        return "Hi";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/products/{productId}")
    public Product getProduct(@PathVariable int productId){     
        return productService.getTopic(productId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/products")
    public void addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        productService.addProduct(product);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/products/{productId}")
    public void updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable int productId) {
        productService.updateProduct(product,productId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/products/{productId}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable int productId) {
        productService.deleteProduct(productId);
    }

}
```

Main Class is

```
package com.prizy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image: Project Structure]

**Note: Question updated with more information.**

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/hi

Comment: `package com.prizy.controller`: Where is your main class?

Comment: Can you post your main class along with the package names?

Comment: Do other methods in this class work?  Any chance the `get...` method name should not be used?  Have you tried changing the name of the method or targeting `/hi` to another method?

Comment: Is your service work correctly when you hit another path then "/hi"?

Comment: From spring 1.4 you can use @PostMapping instead of RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST....) Same goes for GET

Comment: When you start your application, it lists all the REST endpoints exposed from the service, do you see the endpoints from your controller class.? That's could be starting point for you to check

Comment: I guess your `@SpringBootApplication` class is not scanning your controllers because they are not in a subpackage. Make sure your controllers are in a sub package of the package where your application class is.

Comment: Logs from startup? So we can debug.

Comment: Or a link to a GitHub project would help.

Comment: Remove the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation it is redundant ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the scenario I have finally changed the Spring boot version to 1.3.2.RELEASE

After doing this its working fine. 
I am still trying to get the answer why its not working on 1.5.2 Release.

But to resolve this error, i did below change to my POM.xml file

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

After this change , I can see the request mapping urls in logs too:

```
2017-04-19 11:10:49.785  INFO 4236 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello]}" onto public java.lang.String com.epic.controllers.TestController.sayHello()
2017-04-19 11:10:49.786  INFO 4236 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/helloss]}" onto public java.lang.String com.epic.TestControllerTest.sayHello()
2017-04-19 11:10:49.789  INFO 4236 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2
```

Please note that meanwhile I changed the mapping urls names so it may not be same as the question.

Answer (score 1):

check the web.xml file is available or not into src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>web.xml. if not available the craete this file and use the below code.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: He is using Spring Boot which doesn't have a `web.xml`.